# Тест с выбором одного ответа на андроид java

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты

Посоветуйте как можно сделать тест в андроид приложении, в котором можно выбрать один ответ из 4(допустим) и в итоге выводить заключение (вывод) основанный на ответах

Comment: в книгах: П.Дейтел "Android для разработчиков" 2016 2-издание и П.Филлипс "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" 2017 3-издание самым подробным образом разбирается создание приложения-теста (игры-викторины), я бы рекомендовал вам прочитать их и никаких вопросов у вас не останется.

Comment: Вам что конкретно не понятно? Какой писать код? С чего начать? Как лучше сделать? Есть какие-то попытки уже?

Comment: Есть идея такая, загрузить все вопросы и варианты вывода в бд, при нажатии на кнопки зачислить очки к соответствующим вариантам вывода, по окончании теста делать проверку по всем очкам, и выводить тот, который набрал больше всего очков